# Stringify numbers in json as hex (or other) fomat using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Is there an easy way to stringify numbers as hex format using JSON.stringify?
For example if I have a JSON structure:

```
{
    number: 1024
}
```

In this case I want the JSON string output to look like

```
{
    number: 0x400
}
```

JSON.stringify always returns numbers in decimal format (base 10).

Comment: `0x...` formatted numbers are not valid JSON. You'd have to use the replacer function of `JSON.stringify` to format the number to a string `"0x..."`.Why do you want this?

Comment: @phuzi I'm playing around with Ethereum particularly I have an issue with RPC compatibility using the same call on Geth or Parity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`replacer`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) of [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

replacer gets two parameter `key` and `value` being stringifed. in this function as you wanted to change number type from decimal to hex, so we check if the type is number we convert it to hex using `toString()` method with base `16` and if not than we return the value directly without any change.

```js
const obj = { num1:1024,num2:1025,num3:1026,num4:1027 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
  if( typeof value === 'number'){
    return '0x' + value.toString(16)
  }
  return value
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toString(16)` with your number.

```js
var obj = {
  num1: 1024,
  num2: 1025,
  num3: 1026,
  num4: 1027
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => obj[e] = "0x" + obj[e].toString(16))
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: so I have to do this for every number? Sorry if I was not clear enough. I would require this in case of a large JSON object.

Comment: @Alko What difference does it make if the `JSON` is `"\"1024\""` or a `JSON` string having arbitrary `.length`?

Comment: @Alko check the edits. Now you can iterate over the json and convert all the numbers

Comment: also the number must not be a string. I want the json to be encoded in hex format. I tried with "0x400" but the endpoint rejects it while `curl --data '{"number": 0x400}'` works.

Comment: @Alko _"also the number must not be a string"_ `JSON` is a string format. Is the requirement to output a plain JavaScript object?

Comment: Try Number("0x400") and see it will parse back to the original number.

Comment: @ellipsis `0x400` is a valid number `typeof 0x400 // "number"`, though OP asks for `JSON` at  the question

Comment: @CodeManiac it does convert back

Comment: the issue is even if I make a JSON object { number: 0x400 } JSON.stringify will return a string '{ "number": 1024 }' so the number will be converted back into decimal

Comment: I guess I'll have to do this manually, removing " after I stringify the json.

Comment: @CodeManiac I did, but the number returned is still in quotations. I will have to manually get rid of them before sending to the RPC.